# HttpClient form submission with json return

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

Thanks in advance.

We are working on an oAuth2 process and need some help. The requirement given is to POST to the server with form variables embedded, and expect a server response in JSON. The documentation has a similar sequence involving a GET request returning JSON and a very similar method grabs the response just fine. However, in this case it gives an object ref error saying the response is null. We are getting a 200 OK message from server with a content length of 1929, and it says content-type is application/json so I have every reason to believe the content is there somewhere.

```
public rsAccessToken Signup(string Code, string State, string redirect_uri)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            rsAccessToken rt = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URLtoken);
            string grant_type = "authorization_code";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientid, secret));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URLtoken);
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "grant_type", grant_type }, { "code", Code }, { "state", State }, { "redirect_uri", redirect_uri } };
            var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            Task task = client.PostAsync(URLtoken, encodedContent)
           .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
           {
               Task<string> jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               jsonString.Wait();
               rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rsAccessToken>(jsonString.Result);
           });
            task.Wait();

            client.Dispose();

            return rt;
        }
```

the response captured at the taskwithresponse point is:

```
Id = 104, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Connection: keep-alive\r\n  Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 14:41:55 GMT\r\n  ETag: W/\"789-W2Me6TSLLmO4+fEmAtfH4YWXhxs\"\r\n  Set-Cookie: TS0108eb76=0119a2687f0aa2133862c3de61eb2485030f83265a0e1bcb62403e1c777052fccfeacf2df6a14e78b161afc6a43cfc2622532765bc; Max-Age=900; Path=/\r\n  Content-Length: 1929\r\n  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n}"
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: How `response` is populated? Do you intend to use `taskwithresponse`?

Comment: in the get request, the following code is used and response is populated fine. Task task = client.SendAsync(request)
           .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
           {
               Task<string> jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               jsonString.Wait();
               rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Classes.VA.Response>(jsonString.Result);
           });

Comment: I am not sure how response is populated.... I grabbed the lambda expression from a sample online, and when it worked for get...ran down the rabbit hole never looking back. I could use an education in that regard. I am not as well versed with the new task model as I wish I was.

Comment: That was it. Thank you for your response. Changing to taskwithresponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); fixed it. It wasn't logical to me how response was getting populated before, but it was in get, so I didn't think much of it. Really apprecaite your quick response

Comment: Is it possible for you to convert the `Signup` to aysnc type? If yes then you use await at asynchronous operation where you can check the output. I've posted the answer after converting to pure async chain. @Greg - Please check that

Comment: This code is a mess. You need to learn how to use the HttpClient and async/await. Try this out: https://pastebin.com/YRmSC9kP

Comment: @Andy the specs require form fields be a POST not a GET and not json. Thanks for your sample.

Comment: then change it to Post -- either way, that's way more maintainable than what you have

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
public rsAccessToken VeteranSignup(string Code, string State, string redirect_uri)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        rsAccessToken rt = null;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URLtoken);
        string grant_type = "authorization_code";

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientid, secret));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URLtoken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "grant_type", grant_type }, { "code", Code }, { "state", State }, { "redirect_uri", redirect_uri } };
        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        Task task = client.PostAsync(URLtoken, encodedContent)
       .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
       {
           Task<string> jsonString = taskwithresponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           jsonString.Wait();
           rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rsAccessToken>(jsonString.Result);
       });
        task.Wait();

        client.Dispose();

        return rt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `taskwithreponse`
2. Also, you should use the pure aysnc chain. Don't make the aynsc call to sync call.

   ```
    public async Task<rsAccessToken> Signup(string Code, string State, string redirect_uri)
    {
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
           rsAccessToken rt = null;

           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URLtoken);
           string grant_type = "authorization_code";

           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
           var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientid, secret));
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
           var(HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URLtoken))
           {
                 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "grant_type", grant_type }, { "code", Code }, { "state", State }, { "redirect_uri", redirect_uri } };
                 var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
                 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(URLtoken, encodedContent)

                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rsAccessToken>(jsonString.Result);
           }

        return rt;
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: I am modifying based on your post. Give me a second, I have some errors to resolve in the sample you provided

Comment: @Greg - let me know if you need any additional details